# P-values for each column stratified by Disease

Tags: r

I have a data set of the following variety; there are > 40 complications in the real data set.

```
Disease <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
Complication1 <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
Complication2 <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
dataset <- data.frame(cbind(Complication1, Complication2, Disease))


 Complication1      Complcation2      Disease
    0                  1                 1
    0                  1                 1
    0                  1                 1
    0                  1                 1
    1                  0                 0
    1                  0                 0
    1                  0                 0
    1                  0                 0
```

I am trying to calculate the p-value for each complication `complication1` and `complication2` based on whether disease state is present or absent.

I used TableOne but there are some issues with this method and I was wondering how to do this for each column with a loop approach perhaps.

Run TableOne package

```
table1 <- CreateTableOne(vars = xvars, strata = “Disease", data = dataset, test = TRUE)

xvars <- c(“Complciation1", “Complciation2”)

print(table1, smd = T)
```

Output would look something like this for this example

```
                       Stratified by Disease
                            0           1             p    
  n                         4           4                          
  Complication1 (mean (SD)) 0.25 (0.00) 0.75 (0.00)   < 0.03     
  Complication2 (mean (SD)) 0.75 (0.00) 0.25 (0.00)   < 0.03
```

Comment: Can you please show the exact command you are using to produce your table?

Comment: It’s a downloaded dataset so I’m not generating it but as far as the output it’s a package called “tableone”. Don’t really care about the latter though.

Comment: What is it exactly you want to test? What is your null hypothesis? You might need to ask a question over at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ before we can help you with implementation.

Comment: You could use Disease <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
complication1 <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
complication2 <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
sample <- as.data.frame(cbind(complication1, complication2,Disease))

Comment: Null hypothesis --> no statistical difference in complication1 in presence or absence of disease.... Null hypothesis --> no statistical difference in complication2 in presence or absence of disease....

Comment: Yes, but could you show the command? I've never used `tableone`, but if you show me how you called it to produce a table with one variable, I can show you how to put it in a loop or an `lapply` to a big table. Is it `tableone(your_data, Disease, Complication1)`, or `tableone(Disease ~ Complication1, data = your_data)`, or `tableone(data$Disease, data$Complication1)`?? Just show the command you want to generalize.

Comment: table1 <- CreateTableOne(vars = xvars, strata = “Disease", data = dataset, test = TRUE) where xvars <- c(“Complciation1", “Complciation2”)

Comment: View results print(table1, smd = T)

Comment: Thanks! Could you also please edit both this and the data syntax into the question so it's not buried here in comments?

Comment: (And, as a sidenote, stay away from `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`---`cbind()` will create a matrix and if any of your data is non-numeric it will convert all your data to non-numeric. `data.frame(...)` is shorter, more efficient, and safer. `data.frame(Disease, complication1, complication2)` in this case.)

Comment: Fixed see question now.

Comment: A quick statistical remark: make sure to adjust for multiple comparisons, or you'll get a high probability of false positives. R has the `p.adjust` function to do this.